# Wrap function for RxJS map() argument

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have this utility method (used for Angular reactive form dirty checking):

```
   private checkIsDirty(valueChanges: Observable<any>, sourceEntity: any, createEntityFromFormValue: (frmVal: any) => unknown): Observable<boolean> {
      return valueChanges.pipe(
         debounceTime(400),
         distinctUntilChanged(),
         map(createEntityFromFormValue), //// ====> here
         map((frmEntity) => !deepEqualRelaxed(sourceEntity, frmEntity)),
         startWith(false),
         shareReplay()
      );
   }
```

And here's typical `createEntityFromFormValue()` function:

```
   protected createEntityFromFormValue(frmVal: any): unknown {
      try {
         if (areAllPropsFalsy(frmVal)) {
            // if all props are falsy ==> return undefined
            return undefined;
         }

         return new MyCompany(
            frmVal.name ?? "",
            frmVal.shortName ?? "",
            frmVal.phone ?? "",
            frmVal.email ?? "",
            this.company ? this.company.printingMml : true,
            frmVal.licenseNumber,
            frmVal.licenseExpDate,
            this.company ? this.company.id : undefined,
            frmVal.comment
         );
      } catch (e: unknown) {
         console.error(`createCompanyFromValue exception: ${e}`);
         throw e;
      }
   }
```

As you may notice there is a try-catch block inside this method. I'd like to move it out to some wrapper function and use it in `checkIsDirty()` instead. This way I wouldn't do this try-catch everywhere (and eventually forget) but I can't figure out how.

#### Update

I should probably add that wrapping the `createEntityFromFormValue()` is very important because angular/rxjs just quietly swallows the exception, and it's very difficult to find!

Comment: All you're doing is printing a message? You can use `tap({error: e => console.log(... e)})`

Comment: No, not printing

Comment: That was a rhetorical question. Whatever effect you're creating can be managed the same way.

Comment: I just hope there is a way to create a function wrapper and keep same code for `checkIsDirty()`, so `createEntityFromFormValue()` is wrapped.

Comment: Wrapped to do what? You're logging a message and then re-throwing. Any effect like that can be done with the tap operator as shown in my first comment. If you want to catch errors, there's also the `catchError` operator. But if you're just re-trowing it, that's overkill.

Comment: The idea is to wrap that function with try-catch, and have the `console.error()` in the catch. So, as a users I'd supply the `createEntityFromFormValue()` and don't worry about its exceptions. The user (who writes this `createEntityFromFormValue()` func) may forget to handle exceptions, so I need to handle them in the wrapper.

Comment: User must not break the whole process.

Comment: But your function doesn't handle the error. It just re-throws the error.

Comment: That's the point - dev must be informed! Otherwise, angular does not show it. At all! I learned this hard way!

Comment: Wait, you WANT to re-throw it? Then why not use the suggestion from my first comment?

Comment: To put into context, please see this - https://github.com/ngneat/dirty-check-forms/issues/24#issue-1316854972 (but that issue about the overall usage)

Comment: angular doesn't swallow exceptions. That's what `tap()`/`subscribe()`with `{ error: (e) => /*code*/) }` is for. You can also use `catchError`.

Comment: it does, in this case. trust me

Comment: It's not about trust. I don't think you're lying. You're just mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Naive way to just log errors

You can just use `tap` to log errors. This makes logging the error a side-effect of running the observable without further changing the semantics of the observable.

```ts
function checkIsDirty<T, R>(
  sourceEntity: R, 
  createEntityFromFormValue: (frmVal: T) => R
): OperatorFunction<T, boolean> {

  return pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(createEntityFromFormValue),
      tap({error: e => console.error(`Error checkIsDirty: ${e}`)}),
      map(frmEntity => !deepEqualRelaxed(sourceEntity, frmEntity)),
      startWith(false),
      shareReplay()
  );
}
```

## Re-wrap with try/catch

Here's an example of how you might use try-catch

```ts
function checkIsDirty<T, R>(
  sourceEntity: R, 
  createEntityFromFormValue: (frmVal: T) => R
): OperatorFunction<T, boolean> {

  function wrapUserFunction(frmVal: T){
    try {
      return createEntityFromFormValue(frmVal);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(`Error checkIsDirty: ${e}`);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  return pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(wrapUserFunction),
      map(frmEntity => !deepEqualRelaxed(sourceEntity, frmEntity)),
      startWith(false),
      shareReplay()
  );
}
```

or in-line:

```ts
function checkIsDirty<T, R>(
  sourceEntity: R, 
  createEntityFromFormValue: (frmVal: T) => R
): OperatorFunction<T, boolean> {

  return pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(frmVal => {
        try {
          return createEntityFromFormValue(frmVal);
        } catch(e) {
          console.error(`Error checkIsDirty: ${e}`);
          throw e;
        }
      }),
      map(frmEntity => !deepEqualRelaxed(sourceEntity, frmEntity)),
      startWith(false),
      shareReplay()
  );
}
```